# How to get data from another web site

Tags: php, curl

How can I get specific data from another web site, using cURL with PHP?
This is my code:

```
$page = curl_init('http://lookup.cla.base8tech.com/');
$encoded ='';

foreach($_GET as $name=>$value){
    $encoded .= urlencode($name) .'=' .urlencode($value).'&';
}
foreach ($_POST as $name=>$value){
    $encoded .= urlencode($name) .'=' .urlencode($value).'&';
}
preg_match('!\d+!', $encoded, $zip);
print_r($zip);

$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1 );

curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded);
curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_exec($page);
curl_close($page);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple errors in your code. First, to address your main question, you're not quite doing it right with your `cURL` request. To send a `POST` request using `cURL` and retrieve the response, use the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url); // Set cURL url   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); // Send request via POST                                          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // Set POST data                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // curl_exec() returns response   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  

$response = curl_exec($ch); // Return the request response
curl_close($ch);
```

Also, in your code, you use `$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1 );`. This is not necessary, instead just do `$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, -1 );`.

Third, your regular expression is currently invalid. You need to add a `/` to the beginning and end of the string: `preg_match('/!\d+!/', $encoded, $zip);`

Finally, your `foreach` loops are not entirely necessary. You can use the `http_build_query` function instead: `$encoded = http_build_query($_GET) . "&" . http_build_query($_POST);`. This also makes your `substr` line pointless.

Therefore you'll want something like:

```
$encoded = "";

// Check to make sure the variables encoded are actually set
if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_GET)) {
    $encoded = http_build_query($_GET) . "&" . http_build_query($_POST);
} elseif (empty($_POST) && !empty($_GET)) {
    $encoded = http_build_query($_GET);
} elseif (!empty($_POST) && empty($_GET)) {
    $encoded = http_build_query($_POST);
} else {
    $encoded = "";
}

$encoded = http_build_query($_GET) . "&" . http_build_query($_POST);

preg_match('/!\d+!/', $encoded, $zip);
print_r($zip);

$ch = curl_init("http://lookup.cla.base8tech.com/"); // Set cURL url   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); // Send request via POST                                          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded); // Set POST data                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // curl_exec() returns response   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  

$response = curl_exec($ch); // Return the request response
curl_close($ch);
```